# Find all Strings present as keys in a Map<String, Object>, but not in a Set<String>. Java

Tags: java, dictionary, set

Is there a function similar to `set1.removeAll(set2);` that takes a `Map<String, Object>` and removes all keys that are present in `Set<String>`? One can write a small function like the one below, but is there a method in a standard library for doing this?

```
    Map<String, Object> myMap =  ...;
    Set<String> mySet =  ... ;
    for (String string : mySet) {
        if (myMap.containsKey(string)) {
            myMap.remove(string);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove from the [`keySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--), and the changes will be reflected in the `Map`.

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so **changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa**. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined. **The set supports element removal**, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.

```
myMap.keySet().removeAll(mySet);
```